# Getting object null for iframe.contentDocument iframe created iframe using jsdom with required options

Tags: javascript, iframe, jsdom

```
var elementFrame = window.document.createElement('iframe');
    elementFrame.style.display = 'none';
    elementFrame = window.document.body.insertBefore(elementFrame, null);

if (elementFrame.contentDocument) {
    element = elementFrame.contentDocument;
} else if (element.contentWindow) {
    element = elementFrame.contentWindow.document;
}

console.log("Element **********" + element);
```

I am using jsdom with required parameters

```
var path = require("path");
    global.jsdom = require("jsdom");
    global.jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
        ProcessExternalResources: true,
        ProcessExternalResources : ['script', 'frame', 'iframe'],
        FetchExternalResources : ['script','img','css','frame','iframe','link'],
        MutationEvents: true,
        QuerySelector : true
    };
```

I am getting null for contentDocument. What should I do to get the html object for iframe in jsdom?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does what you want it to do, but you might be trying to add the iframe before your document finishes loading.
Add the javascript at the end of your `<body>` tag and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var elementFrame = window.document.createElement('iframe'); 
            elementFrame.style.display = 'none'; 
            elementFrame = window.document.body.insertBefore(elementFrame, null);

        if (elementFrame.contentDocument) {
            element = elementFrame.contentDocument;
        } else if (element.contentWindow) {
            element = elementFrame.contentWindow.document;
        }

        console.log("Element **********" + element);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Df4s2/) with this code.